# How identfy http post API request is from my app?

Tags: android, api, http, post

I run a project which will call API(http post) from my app. The post data includes the user's profile. If the user is valid, he will get a discount coupon. But now, I found if some user calls api from PC (ie. chrome), he will get the coupon too. We only accept user apply coupon form our app for pushing our app usage.

I know I can set a secret key when my app send a http post. But I think if someone uses sniffer software will find the key and use it.

So, my question is how to identify this API request is sent from my app. If not, I will reject this call.

Comment: You can't. You'll need to embed a unique signature, but everything can be spoofed, and any code can be reverse engineered. Not sure how sniffers work, but they might be safe in an HTTPS POST query, but if you store the key in the app itself, that can be cracked open and the point is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try parsing the User-Agent header to help identify the browser being used, version, OS. But you can't be 100% certain.

For examples of User Agent strings, see 
https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings

Answer (score 0):

You should use https/ssh tunnel and authentication/authorization tokens.

So the your keys and tokens are the secrets and https tunnel prevents sniffing